# Is a renter of a room in France required by law to provide a proof of residence?

Tags: rental-property, france

In France every resident is required to possess a proof of residence, which must be a utility bill and a declaration by the landlord if the bill is not in the person's name. French landlords often don't want to provide this document, usually because they don't want their renters to declare their address to any government controlled database so that they are able to not declare the rent for tax purposes without being noticed. In the other hand this creates a huge burden on the renter since a proof of residence is required to obtain many mandatory services, like open a bank account (yes, this is mandatory in France). The rent agreement cannot be used as a proof of residence. If a renter find him/herself in this situation, could this person oblige the landlord to provide this document? Is this document actually mandatory to be provided by the landlord to the renter?

Comment: You might try asking about this on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Just asked there too https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12374/is-a-renter-of-a-room-in-france-required-by-law-to-provide-a-proof-of-residence.

Comment: Good question. My strong intuition is "yes", but I have no idea where to look for authority in French law that this is the case or how one would go about enforcing this law. It is particularly vexing because it hovers on the boundary between private law and public law, which involve very different bodies of law and legal remedies in the French legal system. Finding a way to file a complaint with the Council of State would be faster and cheaper if you could fit it into that box, but it isn't clear that you could. A report to a tax official might also do the trick (or even threatening to do so).

Comment: I know that it is mandatory to give a rent payment receipt that can be used as a residence proof for some public institutions, but banks usually don't accept them.